# Highlight elements of an array in a given order

Tags: java, jquery, arrays, jstl

I have an array of sentences in a list in a given order and another array with part of the sentences from the first array in another order. I am inside the spring MVC framework.

```
ArrayList<String> first = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> second = new ArrayList<>();
Integer len1;
Integer len2;

first.add("Marry ");
first.add("had ");
first.add("a ");
first.add("little lamb.");
second.add("Marry "); //first added
second.add("little lamb."); //second added

len1=first.length();
len2=second.length();
model.addAttribute("first", first);
model.addAttribute("second", second);
model.addAttribute("len1",len1);
model.addAttribute("len2",len2);
```

What i want to do is display the elements of the first array and highlight those that match from the second array but make the highlight so that i can tell which is the first element and which the second by using a gradient. 
I am displaying the first array like so.

```
 <c:forEach var="i" items="${first}" end="${len1}">
 <c:out value="${i}"/>
 </c:forEach>
```

I tried to do it in the forEach but i'm not sure it's the way to do it, at least not the gradient.
The end result should be

Marry had a little lamb.

And if gradient were to be from red to yellow then "Marry" should be highlighted red and "little lamb." yellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not been able to find a solution that makes it so that a gradient is applied to each line mainly because css gradients are applied from top to bottom or left to right and if the text breaks in a column the gradient will be applied left to right on the whole block instead of having each line with it's gradient.
I used bold instead.

This is the solution.

```
<c:forEach var="i" items="${first}" >
              <c:choose><c:when test="${second.contains(i)}">
                  <strong ><c:out value="${i}"/></strong>
              </c:when><c:otherwise>
                  <c:out value="${i}"/>
              </c:otherwise></c:choose>
          </c:forEach>
```

Also i have to credit this answer.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35022587/highlight-text-in-jstl
```