# Highlight text in JSTL

Tags: java, arrays, jstl

I need to display  text using JSTL. There are two arrays.

array a [one, two, three, nine]
array b [nine, one, two]

The displayed text should bold the elements in a that are also in b and leave the rest normal

**one**, **two**, three, **nine**

```
<c:forEach var="i" items="${a}">
              <c:forEach var="j" items="${b}">
                  <c:choose>
                      <c:when test="${i==j}">
                          <strong><c:out value="${i}"/></strong>
                      </c:when>
                      <c:when test="${i!=j}">
                           <c:out value="${i}"/>
                      </c:when>
                  </c:choose>
              </c:forEach>
          </c:forEach>
```

What am i missing? The code displays **one** highlighted and then normal 3 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second `<c:when>` should be a `<c:otherwise>`.

You probably meant to put the `<strong>` and `</strong>` *around* one of the `<c:out>`.

Also, your code would output 4 * 3 = 12 values. Is that what you intended?
If not, perhaps changing `b` to a `List` or `Set`, and using `b.contains(i)` would be what you want.

---

**Update**

If `b` is a `Collection`, preferably a `Set`, then this will do:

```jsp
<c:forEach var="i" items="${a}">
    <c:choose><c:when test="${b.contains(i)}">
        <strong><c:out value="${i}"/></strong>
    </c:when><c:otherwise>
        <c:out value="${i}"/>
    </c:otherwise></c:choose>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: No, i just want to print the 4 values with the 3 that match the second vector being bolded. Also edited @ <strong>. The array is an ArrayList

Comment: Then, as I suggested, change `b` to a `Set` and use `contains()`, using only one loop.

Comment: This is what i have  `<c:forEach var="i" items="${a}">
                  <c:forEach var="j" items="${b}">
                      <c:choose>
                          <c:when test="${i.contains(j)}">
                               <strong><c:out value="${i}"/><strong>
                          </c:when>
                      </c:choose>
                  </c:forEach>
              </c:forEach>`  but leaving it like this bolds everything.

Comment: I'm sorry but i can't make it work. I changed b to a Set using `Set<String> newSet = new HashSet<String>(b);` but i don't know how to make it work in one loop.

Comment: @user10209 You have one loop, and call `contains()` inside it, as updated answer shows.